# OpenAL sound stops OpenGL from drawing

Tags: opengl, openal

I have a scene that is modified when mouse left button is clicked.

My problem is: this modified scene was supposed to appear with a sound, but the scene waits the sounds to finish before it renders itself.

I'm using this function:

```
do {
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
 } while (state == AL_PLAYING);
```

Of course, this function tells the program to wait. But what alternative could I use? if I remove this function, the sound isnt played

I even tried to create a function sound(), that is called after glutPostRedisplay but it still waits the sound complete to render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem, that the sounds stop, is somewhere else. `alGetSourcei` is not required to keep the sound playing.

Anyway you can't do that in a while loop because it will block the update of the windows messages and OpenGL and will prevent the scene from redrawing.

To play it you just need to call `alSourcePlay`, after this you could check each frame if the source is still playing ( if you need to do this for some reason ).